# Ruby on Rails: Checkbox gets unchecked when trying to edit a post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox, ruby-on-rails-5

When i create a new post (passengerride), it is successfully storing multiple value in database. But, when i try to edit the post (passengerride), the checkboxes are getting unchecked.

This is my form:

apps/views/passengerrides/_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @passengerride do |f| %>
        ......
          <div class="form-group ">
            <div class="control-label col-sm-2 requiredField">
              <%= f.label :okwithgender, 'Driver should be:' %>
              <span class="asteriskField">*</span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <div class=" ">
                <div class="checkbox">

                  <label class="checkbox"><input id="okwithgender"  type="checkbox" value="Male" name="passengerride[okwithgender][]">Male</label>

                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">

                  <label class="checkbox"><input id="okwithgender"  type="checkbox" value="Female" name="passengerride[okwithgender][]">Female</label>

                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">

                  <label class="checkbox"><input id="okwithgender"  type="checkbox" value="Other" name="passengerride[okwithgender][]">Other</label>

                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">

                  <label class="checkbox"><input id="okwithgender"  type="checkbox" value="Any Gender" name="passengerride[okwithgender][]">Any Gender</label>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

   ....
<% end %>
```

app/controllers/passengerrides_controllers:

```
  def passengerride_params
      params[:passengerride][:okwithgender] = params[:passengerride][:okwithgender].join(', ')
      params.require(:passengerride).permit(:origin, :destination ... :okwithgender)
  end
```

I guess using this `<%= f.check_box ... %>` will solve the problem, but i'm not sure how to write something equivalent to 
`<input id="okwithgender"  type="checkbox" value="Male" name="passengerride[okwithgender][]">`

Answer (score 1):

You should start using rails form helpers for form fields. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html.

In your case, I think you should try and achieve this using radio buttons as any person will choose just one of these options.

```
<%= f.radio_button :okwithgender, 'Male' %>
<%= f.label :okwithgender, 'Male', value: 'Male' %>
<%= f.radio_button :okwithgender, 'Female' %>
<%= f.label :okwithgender, 'Female', value: 'Female' %>
<%= f.radio_button :okwithgender, 'Other' %>
<%= f.label :okwithgender, 'Other', value: 'Other' %>
<%= f.radio_button :okwithgender, 'Any Gender' %>
<%= f.label :okwithgender, 'Any Gender', value: 'Any Gender' %>
```

To achieve this via checkboxes multiple selection,

```
f.check_box :okwithgender, {multiple: true}, 'Male'
f.label :okwithgender, 'Male', value: 'Male'
f.check_box :okwithgender, {multiple: true}, 'Female'
f.label :okwithgender, 'Female', value: 'Female'
f.check_box :okwithgender, {multiple: true}, 'Other'
f.label :okwithgender, 'Other', value: 'Other'
f.check_box :okwithgender, {multiple: true}, 'Any Gender'
f.label :okwithgender, 'Any Gender', value: 'Any Gender'
```

Comment: I'm building a carpool app, where a user must select the gender of the driver (could be male or both male and female).
I tried this: <%= f.check_box :okwithgender,{},'Male' %>
But its equivalent to:
<input type="checkbox" value="Male" name="passengerride[okwithgender]" id="passengerride_okwithgender">
I need something like this
<input type="checkbox" value="Male" name="passengerride[okwithgender][]" id="passengerride_okwithgender">

Comment: @SainathReddy Edited my answer. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: When i check a value, it is storing the string and the unchecked values are stored as 0. It's storing 0,Male,0,0,0 when i checked male. And it's getting unchecked when i try to edit the form.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably agree that this is easier with Rails form helpers. However, if you don't want to use them, you have to extract the values. So, in your `models/passengerride.rb` I would add:

```
def okwithgender_separate
  okwithgender.split(',')
end
```

and then in your view, each of the inputs would have to have something like:

```
<input 
  id="okwithgender"  
  type="checkbox" 
  value="Any Gender" 
  name="passengerride[okwithgender][]"
  <%= 'checked="checked"' if @passengerride.okwithgender_separate.include? 'Any Gender' %> >
```

or you could add that function to a controller helper to clean it up.

Comment: I tried this, but only the first box is checked, the rest of the selected boxes are getting unchecked in edit page. If I checked female and other, only female is checked in the edit page.